# Why does the browser says my auth is undefined whilst i have assigned it a value?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to protect my route but for some reasons this is the error i am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined`

```
  22 | 
  23 | const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
> 24 |     auth: state.firebase.auth,
  25 | });
```

I passed the auth in the PrivateRoute but I do not know why it is still giving me error.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) =>
                auth.isLoaded && !auth.isEmpty ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{ pathname: "login", state: { from: props.location } }}
                        />
                    )
            }
        />
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: Looks like `state.firebase` is `undefined`. Make sure you're setting the initial state with the `auth` property in the `firebase` reducer.